# setting firebase storage rule to watch for a piece of state in React Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Is it possible to set a firebase storage rule to watch the value of a piece of state?

I am not using firebase auth for my app I just want to use a bucket for file storage. I have a state variable within my app:

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    currentUser: null,
    isAuthed: false
  });
```

If the user is authenticated the `isAuthed` value will flip to true. Therefore would it be possible to write a rule set that looks as so:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if state.isAuthed === true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post raises two questions:
How to pass data to storage rules?
How to check for authentication status without using firebase authentication?

## ✉️ Passing data to storage rules

### File path

You could save your file to the path `/userfiles/authenticated/...` to signal that the file was uploaded by an authenticated user. In the storage rule, you have access to the path through the [match](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/core-syntax) clause:

```
match /userfiles/authenticated/{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
}
```

### Custom metadata

When uploading a file you can set custom metadata [this way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata):

```
const metadata = { customMetadata: { isAuthed: true } };
const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, file, metadata);
```

Then you can [read the metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#resource) in the storage rules:

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.resource.metadata.isAuth == true;
}
```

### Custom claims or custom tokens

[Custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) or [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) allow assigning data to a user in a secure way, this data is then passed to the storage rule.
Custom claims necessitate using firebase authentication, but custom tokens allow you to assign a token from your server without using firebase authentication.
To read the data:

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.token.isAuth == true;
}
```

## Checking authentication status

### Use custom token

The easiest way to ensure only authenticated users can upload is through custom claims or custom token, as detailed above.

### Cryptographic trick

**⚠️ For fun only, [use at your own risks](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2210/245651)**
Let's roll our own crypto protocol to have a secure way of allowing upload only to authenticated users. NB: this does not prevent read access because we cannot provide metadata.

1- An user requests an upload token from your server:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const SECRET = "S3CRET"; // a secret shared by your server and security rules

// If the user is authenticated, send them this upload token:
const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(9).toString('base64');
const data = `${nonce},${filepath},${SECRET}`
const token = { nonce, hash: crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data).digest('base64') };
```

2- You pass the upload token to the storage rule via the file path or custom metadata as described above

3- In the storage rule, you [validate the hash](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.hashing#.sha256):

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if verifyHash(request, allPaths);
}

function verifyHash(request, path){
  let nonce = request.resource.metadata.nonce;
  let hash = request.resource.metadata.hash;
  let hash2 = hashing.sha256(nonce + "," + path + ",S3CRET")).toBase64();
  return hash == hash2; 
}
```

4- profit: only users who have an upload token can upload a file, as a bonus you also enforce the file path, and you could also enhance the token with a timestamp, and enforce some kind of rate limit.